# Chai http attach sets up content type multipart-formdata

Tags: node.js, tdd, chai

I want to pass the file as binary to one of my functions which i want to write the test around using chai http, below is the code:

```
              chai.request('http://localhost:8085')
                .post('/myAPI/' + req.params.id + '/logo')
                .attach('image', fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/resources/IMG_86425.jpg'), 'IMG_86425.jpg')
                .set('Content-Type','image/jpeg')
                .end((err, res) => {
                    should.equal(err, null);
                    res.status.should.equal(200);
                    res.should.be.json;
                    done();
                });
```

Problem is that attach() inherently seem to update the content type to multipart form data in spite of me trying to over ride it with image/jpeg. 
Is there something we can do to override this behaviour of attach() or is there any other way i can post binary data to my function.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

attach is meant to work for multi part form data, for sending file as binary i used:

```
.send(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/resources/IMG_86425.jpg')) 
                .set('Content-Type','image/jpeg')
```

Solves the problem...